# Kubernetes readiness probe failed

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, pingfederate, readinessprobe

We are trying to deploy PingFed in a Kubernetes cluster. We have files *deployment.yml* and *service.yml*, but the pod is throwing CrashBackLoop error after trying to reach the server profile with a readiness probe error. We have tried everything with changing the service type to tinkering with deployment and service YAML files, but nothing seems to be working.

#### This is the *deployment.yml* file

[image]

[image: Service.yml]

[image: POD error]

#### All the pods, services, deployment running in the namespace

[image: All the pods, services, deployment running in the namespace]

Comment: Service.yaml


apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pingfederate
  labels:
    role: pingfederate
    tier: console
    version: 10.1.5
spec:
  ports:
  - name: console
    port: 9999
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9999
  selector:
    role: pingfederate
    tier: console
    version: 10.1.5
  type: LoadBalancer

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Please edit your question and include the code as text (formatted as a code block).

Comment: Welcome to the community! First as already asked, please replace you screenshots with actual text/code. Then, you can try to add `initialDelaySeconds` to your readiness probe as @San suggested below. If it doesn't work, remove completely healthcheck to have pod running and then using `curl` test if this application based on this container actually serves on port `9999` and `/pingfederate/app`.

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestions. I'm fairly new on this platform, will improve on that. 
@moonkotte Let me try if that works.

Comment: Can you please [make](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68413879/edit) the requested changes? You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68413879/edit) (change) your question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 2):

I don't see initialDelaySeconds in the readiness probe. So, I guess that might be the reason the readiness probe is failing. I would set it to the time it takes for the application to come up.

**initialDelaySeconds**: Number of seconds after the container has started before liveness or readiness probes are initiated. Defaults to 0 seconds. Minimum value is 0.

```
readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path:
        port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I would check and make sure a couple of things:

1. Check that 9999 port is in fact exposed on the container, check the dockerfile if you can, I can already see it's opened up on the deployment.
2. If it is, I noticed your scheme on probes is set to https, should that be http instead?

Comment: Yes it is exposed on the container. 
Tried both of them but it did not resolve the issue